# Making merge sort to use only (n/2 + 1) extra space in java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, indexoutofboundsexception, mergesort

I'm trying to make the merge sort to use only (n/2 + 1) extra space and still O(n log n) time. This is my homework.

The original quesetion:

> Write the non-recursive version of merge sort. Your program should run
>   in O(n log n) time and use n/2 + O(1) extra spaces.

The program will split an array in to two like normal merge sort. 
The left part will be in another array, which is ceil(n/2) long, so it will fit the requirement. 
The right part will be in the original array. So it will be half in-place sorting
Sorry, I don't know how to explain further.
I think this is basically correct. But I kept on facing OutOfBounds error.
I know the code is quite long and messy. But can anyone help me about that?
I spent about 5 hours to implement this. Please help me.

```
package comp2011.lec6;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort {

    public static void printArr(int[] arr){
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int[] arr){
        if(arr.length<2) {
            return;
        }
        int n, lBegin, rBegin;
        n = 1;
        int[] leftArr = new int[arr.length - (arr.length/2)];

        while(n<arr.length) {
            lBegin = 0;
            rBegin = n;



            while(rBegin + n <= arr.length) { 
                mergeArrays(arr, lBegin, lBegin+n, rBegin, rBegin+n, leftArr);
                lBegin = rBegin+n;
                rBegin = lBegin+n;
            }
            if(rBegin < arr.length) {
                mergeArrays(arr, lBegin, lBegin+n, rBegin, arr.length, leftArr);
            }
            n = n*2;
        }
    }


    public static void mergeArrays(int[] array, int startL, int stopL, int startR, int stopR, int[] leftArr) {

//          int[] right = new int[stopR - startR + 1];
//          int[] left = new int[stopL - startL + 1];

//          for(int i = 0, k = startR; i < (right.length - 1); ++i, ++k) {
//              right[i] = array[k];
//          }
        System.out.println("==============");
        System.out.println("stopL: " + stopL +" startL: " + startL);
            for(int i = 0, k = startL; i <= (stopL - startL); ++i, ++k) {
                System.out.println(leftArr[i]);
                leftArr[i] = array[k];
            }

//          right[right.length-1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            leftArr[stopL - startL] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            System.out.println("leftArr: " + Arrays.toString(leftArr));
            System.out.println("RightArr: " + Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, startR, stopR)));
            System.out.println("before: " + Arrays.toString(array));

//          for(int k = startL, m = 0, n = startR; k < stopR; ++k) {
            System.out.println("StartL: " + startL + " StartR: " + stopR);
            for(int k = startL, m = 0, n = startR; ( (k < stopR)  ); ++k) {
                System.out.println("k: " + k);
                System.out.println("Left: " + leftArr[m]);
                System.out.println("Right: " + array[n]);
                System.out.println("Array[k] before: " + array[k]);
//              if(leftArr[m] == Integer.MAX_VALUE){
//                  System.out.println("YES");
//              }
                if( (leftArr[m] <= array[n]) || (n >= stopR) ) {
                    System.out.println("Left is smaller than right");
                    array[k] = leftArr[m];
                    m++;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Right is smaller than left");
                    array[k] = array[n];
                    System.out.println("right: " + array[k]);
                    n++;
                }
                System.out.println("Array[k] after: " + array[k]+"\n");
            }
            System.out.println("after " + Arrays.toString(array));
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[] { 5, 2, 4, 12, 2, 10, 13, 1, 7 };
        mergeSort(array);
        printArr(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it. I think the time complexity issue is ok(?) But I think the space problem is more difficult. May be my question is confusing. I've include the correct question. n/2 should be the main issue

Comment: OP: you just pasted the code you happen to have after five hours work, together with commented-out code and a lot of print statements. If you took some time to prepare this post with cleaner code, it would attract more serious looks.

Comment: I'm sorry. I will try to clean it up a liitle bit. Thank's for your advice. Any response will still make me feel better cause that means there are still people trying to help me.

Comment: @TszFungLi - the sequence should be merge sort right half of arr using leftArr as temp buffer, result in right half of arr. Then copy left half of arr into leftArr, merge sort leftArr, using left half of arr as temp buffer, result in leftArr. Then merge leftArr, right half of arr back into arr. Missing is a check for rBegin >= arr.length, in which case the code should copy from lBegin to arr.length.

Comment: @TszFungLi - Note that lBegin+n == rBegin, so in mergeArrarays, stopL will always equal startR, so only one of these parameters is needed, not both, for example, startL, startR, stopR. You can use #define stopL startR if you want different names for the same parameter. From my previous comment, the order of sorting halves doesn't matter, it just needs to end up with sorted data in leftArr and the right half of arr to do a final merge back into arr.